# How can I define an owner to an empty_dir using container_image or container_layer from bazel rules_docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, bazel, container-image

From the [PR](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/pull/310/files) that implemented empty_dirs, it seems there's support for defining dir owners (with the names argument) and mode into the add_empty_dir method of TarFile class.

But the container_image rule (and container_layer) supports only mode.

This works:

```
container_image(
    name = "with_empty_dirs",
    empty_dirs = [
        "etc",
        "foo",
        "bar",
    ],
    mode = "0o777",
)
```

But this returns an error: "ERROR: (...) no such attribute 'names' in 'container_image_' rule":

```
container_image(
    name = "with_empty_dirs",
    empty_dirs = [
        "etc",
        "foo",
        "bar",
    ],
    names = "nginx",
)
```

Do we need to “[write a customized container_image](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#imageimplementation)” if we want to add support for owner of empty_dirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a BUILD file, the attribute you're looking for is `ownername`. See the [pkg_tar reference documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/blob/main/pkg/docs/reference.md#pkg_tar) documentation for more details. Also, I don't think you can pass it directly to `container_image`, you have to create a separate `pkg_tar` first. Like this:

```py
pkg_tar(
    name = "with_empty_dirs_tar",
    empty_dirs = [
        "etc",
        "foo",
        "bar",
    ],
    ownername = "nginx.nginx",
)

container_image(
    name = "with_empty_dirs",
    tars = [":with_empty_dirs_tar"],
)
```

In general, `container_image` has a subset of `pkg_tar` as direct attributes to make simple forms of adding files, but for complex use cases you should create a `pkg_tar` yourself for full access to all of its features for adding/arranging files and setting their ownership.

The `names` you see in that PR is a variable in a Python helper tool which the BUILD file rules use as part of the implementation. There's a layer of abstraction between what you write in a BUILD file and that Python code.

Comment: It worked with `owner = "<id>.<id>"` for us, `ownername` was not.